# Between in mysql where clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, date, where-clause, between

I am trying to select data from a date range using `BETWEEN` in the where clause,But it does not return the correct result.The date field is in the format `'mm/dd/YYYY'` and the type is `varchar`
My query,

```
select * from time_track where track_date between '01/01/2015' and '01/21/2015'
```

But the result contain data with year 2014.

Can anyone please help me

Comment: convert both of your between value to datetme and check

Comment: Because the type of the field is `VARCHAR` you are comparing strings, not dates. And strings are sorted using the order they have in the dictionary. There is no such thing as "year" in a field of type `VARCHAR`. Change the field type to `DATE` and it will work. Use `'2015-01-01'` and `'2015-01-21'` for the dates you compare with (they are not `DATE`s but also strings but because they have the correct format, `YYYY-MM-DD`, MySQL can cast them to dates without problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
SELECT * FROM `time_track` where DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(track_date, '%c/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-21'
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to convert the date string to a real date

```
select * from time_track 
where STR_TO_DATE(track_date ,'%d/%m/%Y') between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-21'
```

#### Or even better use the date data type for that column.

Then you don't need to convert the data in your queries and can make use of indexes which makes it run super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try on this formate
select * from time_track where track_date >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND track_date <= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

First convert two dates you have selected

```
$from=strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($yourfromdate)))
$to=strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($yourtodate)))

select * from time_track where track_date>='$from' and track_date<='$to'
```

Answer (score 0):

the format of your date is incorrect.
You must use this format in your query: yyyy-mm-dd.

select * from time_track where track_date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-21'

Marco

Answer (score 0):

For mysql between clause to work expectedly, ideal values would be integer, date, time or datetime. Try changing the datatype from varchar to datetime. That would do your comparison job.